# Re-using complex types defined in 1 XSD in other XSDs

Tags: xsd, global, code-reuse

I am new to XML schemas and would like to reuse a particular complex type and it's associated simple type globally across multiple XSD files. Below is chunk of code that I'd like to use globally:

```
    <element name="Operational">
            <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="Status" type="StatusType"/>
                <element name="Description" type="string"/>
            </sequence>
            </complexType>
    </element>

.
.
.

<simpleType name="StatusType">
    <restriction base="string">
        <enumeration value="Success"/>
        <enumeration value="Error"/>
        <enumeration value="Warning"/>
        <enumeration value="Other"/>
    </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

Can you guys please let me know if this is possible & if so, how can I do this so that I can just refer/call this complex type(& the associated StatusType declaration)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.  The construct you may need to read up on is the XSD `include` element.

If the Operational element and its StatusType are declared in an XSD schema document (let us call it 'operational.xsd') for namespace NS1, then other schema documents for the same namespace can make those declarations part of the schema they are defining, by including a reference to operational.xsd.  In the simple case, we might have:

```
<!--* don't do this at home, at least not this way ... *-->
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="..." 
            xmlns:tns="NS1"
            targetNamespace="NS1" >
  <xsd:include schemaLocation="operational.xsd"/>
  <xsd:element name="e" type="tns:StatusType"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="t">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element ref="tns:Operational"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <!--* these aren't useful declarations, they just
      * illustrate the syntax. *-->
</xsd:schema>
```

Multiple inclusions of the same schema document in several places is a good way to create interoperability problems, so in fact the simple pattern illustrated above should usually be avoided in favor of something slightly more verbose but less error-prone:

- Distinguish two classes of schema documents:  *normal* schema documents and *driver* documents.
- Group declarations into normal schema documents in whatever way you find helpful.
- Normal schema documents may need to import other namespaces, but when they do they should never specify a schema location for that other namespace, just a namespace name.
- Normal schema documents should never contain any xsd:include elements.
- Driver documents import and include whatever schema documents should be combined to form a schema for a given purpose.  Unlike normal schema documents, driver documents do specify schema locations on their xsd:import elements.

This helps ensure that no specific schema document is ever imported or included more than once, and thus eliminates a large class of bugs in XSD processors and interoperability problems among processors.

Comment: If I have the following to refer to the operation.xsd which contains the Operational definition along with StatusType definition:
<xsd:include schemaLocation="operational.xsd"/>
Can I simply use the following statement
<xsd:element ref="tns:Operational"/>
to refer to the entire deinfition or I need to declare a complex type & include an element as a placeholder something like the following that's mentioned above:
<xsd:element name="e" type="tns:StatusType"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="t">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element ref="tns:Operational"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

Comment: The former; no placeholder declarations are needed.  You refer to an element declaration, of course, only in the context of some complex type; you don't need a top-level reference.